# Архитектура работы с вэбсокетами

Tags: php, websocket, workerman

Я пишу игру "Морской бой". Для того, чтобы обмениваться информацией с клиентом, я собираюсь использовать вэбсокеты, но я ещё никогда до этого с ними не работал (буду использовать библиотеку Workerman).
У меня Backend на PHP (использую самописный фреймворк, который похож на Laravel). И клиент на VueJS3. Насколько я понимаю, мне нужно будет создать отдельный проект с вэбсокет сервером, который в свою очередь будет обмениваться информацией с фронтендом и бэкендом. Я прав? Или обычно используют другую архитектуру?